# Accent characters are showing weird using curl

Tags: php, curl, utf-8, character-encoding, constantcontact

I am trying to add contacts to **Constant Contact account using V3 API**. Some  user data contain accent characters, when I add these it is showing as `unicode` characters in constant contact account.

**For example**
First name is *GÒKÜL* and last name is *NÁTH*. It is showing in constant contact as **Gu00d2Ku00dcL**  and **Nu00c1TH**. I want to show these as original.

I think issue is in my curl function to add/update contact. Below is the code

```
function  updateContact($access_token,$contactid,$entry){
    $ch = curl_init();
    $base = 'https://api.cc.email/v3/';
    $url = $base . '/contacts/'.$contactid;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    $authorization = 'Authorization: Bearer ' . $access_token;
    $ct = 'Content-Type: application/json;';
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array($authorization, $ct));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);           
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $entry);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
}
```

I tried `$ct = 'Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8';` and `$result = utf8_decode(curl_exec($ch));` But not working.

I think someone can help me..

Answer (score 1):

Those are not 'unicode' characters, they look a bit like Unicode Escape sequences, However, a backslash is missing. You should not be getting `Gu00d2Ku00dcL`, but `G\u00d2K\u00dcL`.

My hope is that those backslashes are actually there and something went wrong with sharing this output. If this is the case, the easiest way to parse these is to use the `json_decode` function.

If those backslases are really missing, then this suggests that the server you are working with is broken, and there's no easy fix for this. In that case you might want to contact who runs this server and let them know.